# writing and opening xlsx file on MAC using numbers

Tags: r, macos, xlsx, openxlsx

I am trying to write a xlsx file on MAC using the following the code.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(openxlsx)
fn<-“RTest.xlsx”
wb<-createWorkbook()
HomeSheet = addWorksheet(wb,“Home”)
writeData(wb,HomeSheet,“R Test”,startCol = 2,startRow = 2)
saveWorkbook(wb,fn,overwrite = T)
```

When I try to open the using the Numbers app, it says file format invalid. But I tried opening another xlsx file that was manually created, it was able to open it.

I am not sure if there is something wrong with the code or if there is something that I am missing. I am new to MAC so dont have much idea about it.

Comment: This appears to be an existing issue with `openxlsx`, see e.g. https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/316.  Perhaps you can try using other packages e.g. `XLConnect`.

Comment: XLConnect will work much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(XLConnect)
wb = loadWorkbook("RTest.xlsx")
new_dataset = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Home", header = TRUE)
```